# Generating a Baseline Profile for a specific flow

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, android-jetpack-compose, baseline-profile

After rooting the emulator, creating the benchmark module, and following all the other steps I managed to generate a Baseline Profile. Here's the code:

```
import androidx.benchmark.macro.ExperimentalBaselineProfilesApi
import androidx.benchmark.macro.junit4.BaselineProfileRule
import androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner
import androidx.test.uiautomator.By
import androidx.test.uiautomator.Until
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@OptIn(ExperimentalBaselineProfilesApi::class)
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
class BaselineProfileGenerator {

  @get:Rule
  val rule = BaselineProfileRule()

  @Test
  fun generate() = rule.collectBaselineProfile(
    "com.bowerydigital.bend"
  ) {
    startActivityAndWait()
    device.wait(Until.hasObject(By.text("Wake Up")), 30_000)
    device.findObject(By.text("Wake Up")).click()
  }
}
```

Here, the rule generates a baseline profile that contains everything, from the launch of the app until the opening of the second screen. However, what I'm trying to do is launch the app and wait for its loading separately, and then create the baseline profile. Basically, I need to generate the baseline profile only from the click of the element in the list to the loading of the screen associated with that click. I tried different things (like defining another method with the `@before` annotation) but since I'm not very familiar with Junit4 and testing in general I cannot find a way to do it.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Is there any particular reason to skip the login screen? You can e.g. inject the logged in state into your app by using a build flag that would be just for the benchmark  variant, or, using broadcast for the benchmark variant.

Comment: Hi @mlykotom! I'd like to also have the login screen inside the flow. Unfortunately, the baseline generated file is way too big around 4.6 MB, so I tried to have as few operations as possible in terms of UI to shorten the file.

Comment: Is the size for the human readable form = the text file? If so, then you may not need to worry about it, because once you build the app with the profile applied, the profile gets compressed to binary form, which should be very very small.